# I am failing to import a database to the live server getting an error 1045

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm trying to import a database from localhost to my live server using phpmyadmin but I keep getting this error

> Error
>
> SQL query:
>
> --
>   -- Database: `tendo`
>   --  CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `tendo` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
>
> MySQL said: Documentation   #1044 - Access denied for user
>   'ronesamp'@'%' to database 'tendo'

How do I get around this and successfully import the database

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the user `ronesamp`@`%` does not have access to that database. You may want to import the database as `root` instead of as `ronesamp`, then add permissions to the `ronesamp` user after the database has been imported.